# Due to Proguard I am getting this error for list iterator

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

That is my stack trace,
When I am running my app in debug it runs perfectly fine 
but
when I am running my app in release mode it gives below error when I click on list item.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                      at dkw.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at dmh.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at dmh.success(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Comment: we'd need to see some code.

Comment: Also because you're using retrofit, check the proguard section in http://square.github.io/retrofit

Comment: @JoaoSousa which part of code you need progaurd one or api class code or else?????

Answer (score 3):

I can assume that the list is empty due to GSON not deserialising the JSON properly since your POJO got obfuscated.

In your class that contains the list you're trying to iterate on annotate your variables with `@SerializedName("json_variable_name_here")`
So for example if JSON is:

```
{
"name":"alice"
"foo" : "bar",
    }
```

Your POJO should look like:

```
@SerializedName("name")
String name;

@SerializedName("foo")
String foo;
```

Comment: got the error as there is error from api i am hitting.